# Writing to a struct element in c

Tags: c, struct

I have the following struct:

```
struct      fdtable
{
    int     fd;
    char    *ptr;
};
```

and in my code, I can declare a variable to it, and assign some values in the main, and this works.

```
int main()
{
    static struct fdtable   table[100];
    int                     i;

    table[0].fd = 5;
    table[1].fd = 6;
    table[0].ptr = strdup("Hello");
    table[1].ptr = strdup("How do you do?");
    printf("fd1: %i, ptr1: %s\n", table[0].fd, table[0].ptr);
    printf("fd2: %i, ptr2: %s\n", table[1].fd, table[1].ptr);
    printf("fd3: %i, ptr3: %s\n", table[2].fd, table[2].ptr);
    table[1].ptr = remaining(table[1].ptr);
    printf("fd2: %i, ptr2: %s\n", table[1].fd, table[1].ptr);
    i = readtable(9, tableptr);
    printf("fd3: %i, ptr3: %s, i: %i\n", table[2].fd, table[2].ptr, i);
    return (0);
}
```

However in my `readtable` function I also want to change some elements and it doesn't seem to work.

```
unsigned int    readtable(int fd, struct fdtable *ptrtable)
{
    unsigned int    i;
    unsigned int    j;

    if (fd == 0)
        return (0);
    i = 1;
    while (fd != ptrtable[i].fd && ptrtable[i].ptr != 0 && i < 100)
        i++;
    if (i == 100)
    {
        j = 1;
        while (ptrtable[j].fd != 0)
            j++;
    ----ptrtable[j].fd = fd;----
        return (j);
    }
    else
        return (i);
}
```

I'm probably just not understanding something simple about how to use a struct.

Comment: What is `tableptr` in `main`?  Is that some hidden global?  Or is this not the code you're running?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? What does it do? Besides, if you intended to pass `table` to your function, notice that nothing is preventing the second `while` loop from accessing out of bounds of the array, and writing there.

Comment: Your array is static and therefore initialized to 0. Passing a `NULL` pointer to printf causes undefined behavior. In some implementations a `"(nul)"` is printed but you should not rely on that.

Comment: From [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "Post the question and respond to feedback. After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments."

Comment: @TomKarzes `tableptr` is a typo, I meant to write `table`.

@aulven I mean that the final printf does not print a changed `table[2].fd` as intended, even though it does find that `[2]` is available.

@Gerhardh indeed it prints (null).

Comment: The idea is to create a table of char pointers indexed by fd, so that fd is input and then the program will use the char pointer under that fd. (it is a testing program for a larger one)

Answer (score 1):

So, I was calling the pointer in the wrong way at the while loop, such that it only incremented once, and never entered the `i=100` condition. I think it was a notation mistake. This code works:

```
... 
i = 1;
while ((ptrtable + i)->fd != fd && i < 100)
    i++;
if (i == 100)
{
    j = 1;
    while (ptrtable[j].fd != 0 && j < 100)
        j++;
    (ptrtable + j)->fd = fd;
    return (j);
}
...
```